# Вызов delete[] для nullptr не приводит к падению приложения?

Tags: c++, указатели, память

Почему мне подсвечиваются подсказки для массивов где я делаю проверку на `nullptr` перед вызовом `delete[]`, получаю подсказку о том что вызов `delete[]` для `nullptr` не производит никаких эффектов?

Это правда, или это лишь поддержка с какого-то стандарта, или подсказка о том что я в коде нигде не заполняю массив, и его можно спокойно удалять даже с значением `nullptr`?

Comment: Что такое "массив с значением nullptr"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Стандарт утверждает, что оператору `delete` (`delete[]`) можно смело передавать `nullptr` - просто в этом случае оператор не будет делать ничего (см. п. 5.3.5.2 стандарта).

> ...значение операнда delete может представлять собой нулевое указательное значение, либо указатель на объект-немассив, созданный посредством некоторого предыдущего new-выражения, либо быть указателем на подобъект (1.8) базового класса объекта-немассива (глава 10). В противном случае поведение программы не определено.

Примерно то же говорится и для оператора `delete[]`:

> ...значение операнда операции delete может быть нулевым указательным значением, либо указателем, полученным в результате некоторой предыдущей операции new-выражение для массива.

Comment: Бывают ли исключительные случаи в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду генерацию исключений? Нет.

Comment: Да, генерацию исключений

Comment: По-хорошему, `delete`, как и деструкторы, не должны генерировать исключения. В случае `delete` стандарт гарантирует, что если деструктор не генерирует исключения, то и оператор его генерировать не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, во-первых, операторы `delete`/`delete []` в принципе невозможно вызвать ни с каким `nullptr`. `nullptr` имеет тип `std::nullptr_t` и использовать значение этого типа в качестве операнда этих операторов не получится.

Операндом `delete`/`delete []` должен являться либо указатель на объектный тип, либо класс, приводимый к такому указателю. Если указатель является null-указателем, то `delete`/`delete []` просто ничего не делает. Null-указатель и `nullptr` - это совершенно разные вещи.

Во-вторых, испокон веков в С и С++ (и далеко за их пределами) было принято придерживаться негласного соглашения о том, что средства освобождения ресурсов ничего не делают в ответ на нулевой хендл ресурса. Точно так же, как функция `free()` ничего не делает в ответ на null-указатель, операторы `delete/delete[]` ничего не делают в ответ на null-указатель. Этого негласного правила придерживаются во многих API. (`fclose` с этой точки зрения является неприятным исключением).

Comment: В некоторых реализациях (насколько помню, в HP-UX так когда-то было) `free(0)` приводила к segfault

Comment: @avp: Ну это уже частные баги конкретных реализаций...

Comment: @AnT Вроде как это - безопасность `free(NULL)` - появилось в каких-то более новых стандартах, а изначально этого не было?